# Solving $\cos(2x) + \cos(x) = \cos\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

How would you go about solving the trigonometric equation below? Thank you.

> $$\cos(2x) + \cos(x) = \cos\left(\frac{3}{2}x\right)$$

I'm not sure how best to rewrite the right-hand side.

Comment: I think you need http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: I think you can't solve this by algebaric methods

Comment: WolframAlpha computes $\cos(x/2)(2\cos(x) - 1)$ as an alternative form of $\cos(3/2x)$, just checked. How does it get to that point?

Comment: @Djura Marinkov how would you solve it?

Comment: @Fehniix Numerically, finding x values approximately.

Comment: I find your notation to be somewhat ambiguous. Is the argument $\frac{3}{2x}$ or $\frac{3x}{2}$?

Comment: It is $\frac{3x}{2}$, the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to simplify RHS. Use $$\cos(x)+\cos(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$ and it is simple from there.

---

If you do want to simplify RHS you might write $\cos\left(\dfrac{3x}{2}\right)=\cos\left(3\cdot \dfrac{x}{2}\right)$. Now \begin{align*}\cos(3x)&=\cos(x+2x)\\&=\cos(x)\cos(2x)-\sin(x)\sin(2x) \tag{cosine of sum}\\&=\cos(x)(2\cos^2(x)-1)-2\sin^2(x)\cos(x)\tag{double angle identities}\\&=\cos(x)\left[2\cos^2(x)-2\sin^2(x)-1\right]\tag{common factor} \\&=\cos(x)\left[2\cos(2x)-1\right]\tag{double angle identity}\end{align*} Plug in $\dfrac{x}{2}$ to get $\displaystyle \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left[2\cos(x)-1\right]$ as written in W|A.

If you choose this approach, you might want to write LHS the following way $$\cos(x)+\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)-1=\left[2\cos(x)-1\right]\left[\cos(x)+1\right]$$ and then use again $\cos(x)=2\cos^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)-1$.

---

Finding solutions: using the first approach we have $$2\cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)\implies \cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)\left[2\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1\right]=0$$ Thus \begin{align*}\frac{3x}{2}&=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k&&\implies x=\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\pi k \\ \frac{x}{2}&=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k &&\implies x=\pm \frac{2\pi}{3}+4\pi k\end{align*}

Comment: As per the first method, that should be the prosthaphaeresis formula, correct? I would obtain all $\frac{3}{2}x$ components, right? How would I go from there? Just compare the arguments? - As per the second one, *why* could you first compute $\cos(3x)$ and *then* plug in $\frac{x}{2}$? Could I do the same with different fractions? Thank you so much.

Comment: I managed to get only two out of three solutions. They are: $[x = \pm\frac{2}{3}\pi + 4k\pi, x = \frac{\pi}{3} + k\frac{2}{3}\pi]$, and I could get only the first two, in $\pm$. How about the third one?

Comment: @Fehniix, I've edited my post and added solutions. I believe that you canceled $\cos(1.5x)$ without checking $\cos(1.5x)=0$. Also, if you take some formula, you can plug in whatever you want.